# Decimals - I try to use "." gives error in one place I try "," gives in another place

Tags: c#, decimal

I insert for example 12.45
gives me error here:

//Input string was not in a correct format

```
deposit = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

If I insert 12,45
gives me error here:

//Incorrect syntax near ','

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Here is already after the part where it gives error on top, and the value already works up there, but down here not

Here shows that up there works, but I insated with "," but appears with "."

[image]

Comment: The debugger is showing you the number with a period as the decimal point by default it is not culturally sensitive - it's just a number! Formatting a number with a comma is for your frontend

Comment: but I can't enter data with either dots or commas @phuzi

Comment: The screenshot showing the value 12.45 is misleading then, it looks like you managed to enter the value `"12.45"` which was successfully parsed. Please explain what you mean by _"I can't enter data with either dots or commas"_

Comment: Can you post more code so we can see a bit more of what you're doing / trying to achieve.  I don't see an error with your first line of code, other than if there's something strange going on with the type of _deposit_.  In addition, what are you trying to achieve with _var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();_  I'm not seeing what relevance this line has to the question

Comment: A database is normally fixed for dots here. But decimal.Parse is culture dependant so might use dot or comma or whatever the current OS settings saying about the decimal separator. Indirect answer. Don't use a string as number in your database. Use the type you need, here looks like decimal, and only use that type to talk to the database. Means use parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to correctly parse a number using a comma `"12,45"` instead of a period `"12.45"` there are a number of overloads that will allow you to specify the decimal separator in different ways:

For example, using German culture info (I don't know what culture you're using)

```cs
var deposit = decimal.Parse("12,45", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```